# How should I connect my Lutron Casetas switch with only one hot (black) wire?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Within the wall switch box, there is a single black wire, neutral wire, and ground wire. I'm installing the Lutron Caseta dimmer (doesn't require a neutral wire connection). On the Casetas, there are TWO black wires. How do you recommend I connect the two components?

Comment: The white is likely the hot, black the switch leg. Can you use a voltage meter measuring voltage on white to ground and black to ground? A picture would also be great.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour].

Comment: What makes you think that is a neutral wire?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, what you called a neutral wire (I assume colored white) is actually the hot coming from the light box (technically, there should be a black stripe of tape or paint near the end, but this is often omitted) and the black is the switched hot going back to the light. This is called a switch loop.

If you had a true neutral in the switch box, it would either be a non-connected white or two whites connected together.

Connect one black from the dimmer to the black wire, the other black from the dimmer to the white and ground to ground.

Comment: Marked or unmarked the white being switch load would be an NEC violation. The configuration of using white for hot prevents polarity confusion presented by two whites connected to light fixture.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease Wouldn't using /2 NM-B as a switch loop require using the white as switched hot? Assuming it was pre-code requiring neutrals in switch boxes.

Comment: @DoxyLover -- white is supposed to be always-hot in /2 (old style) switch loops to make it identifiable as a hot -- see NEC 200.7(C) point 1